# VB.net C# number generator

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a generator that has 4 constant numbers like this:

```
5395-5958-2009-3888 543:8933
5395-5958-2009-3888 456:3834
5395-5958-2009-3888 323:3874
```

Basically think of a gift card, the pin changes. 
I have no idea where to start but it's for my college class.

Ive tried

```
Random rnd = new Random();

int x = rnd.Next(0, 9);
```

but then the 4 constant numbers wont stay the same
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAmys.png)

Comment: Can you show us a bit more code ? The one you've shown actually generate 1 random number between 0 and 9

Comment: if the 4 numbers at the front are constant, just generate the last 2 numbers.

Comment: @Cid actually generate 1 random figure between 0 and 8. from 0 to 9 he would need `rnd.Next(0,10)`

Comment: Simply generate the changing part, and append that to the part that stays the same (in string equivalents); that should do the trick

Comment: You're "Deadly Famous" and this is for a college class?  Are you the guy who played Carl on The Walking Dead who is now apparently enrolled at UGA?  That would be a spot-on handle.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;

namespace ConsoleApplication108
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int[] numbers = new int[4];
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                numbers[i] = rand.Next(1000, 10000);
            }

            string prefix = string.Join("-", numbers);

            for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                int threeDigits = rand.Next(100, 1000);
                int lastNumber = rand.Next(1000, 10000);

                Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}:{2}", prefix,threeDigits, lastNumber);

            }


            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Almost what I want, but I want the first 4 numbers the same like
400 300 200 100 354:39484
400 300 200 100 154:12484
I need it to loop also so it generates a lot

Comment: So close what I need, except I need these specific numebers, my professor wrote this.

Make a generation of numbers that have the same constant numbers for the first values:
6006491266305597
then the next three numbers should be random
After you want a pin : 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0, thats random
after it should be looped, this loop should make it random until u stop it.

Finally, you must be able to have it save automatically in the folder its in.
It should look like this after it's done

6006491266305597398:3998
6006491266305597123:1357
6006491266305597977:4887

Comment: What is wrong with my code?  Looks like the sample you posted.

Comment: Its close, but the space has to be gone, and it needs to be them exact numbers, so what your code does is basically generate new numbers.
I need the same numbers to loop, then the last 3 to change + the pin to change

Comment: I got rid of the space.  Do not understand the other issue.

Comment: Not sure how to explain but ill try my best.
Look at these two pictures:
https://imgur.com/LBomYOK
https://imgur.com/Wv2tMal

In the second picture them 4 numbers ( 16 digits ) are changed, but I need them to stay the same. So they should be:
6006-4912-6630-5597

the other 3 numbers in it should be changed, then the numbers after : should be changed

Comment: Well thanks, Ill figure out the rest, Im not sure how to explain any better